# Add div class with php in jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

**My variable contains a color name. My example:**

```
<?php
$myvar = blueColour;
?>
```

I need to add this value to body of a html page using jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(body).addClass("<?php echo $myvar; ?>");
</script>
```

Can I use php inside jQuery this way? Thank you.

**EDIT: its an wordpress site. I use this in a if to add that class on a specific page template.**

Comment: yes you can but doing it this way is pointless -> why not just echo the class directly on the body? `body class="<?php echo $myvar; ?>"` - for clarity

Comment: Yes you can if you are using a `.php` or a mvc. But if it is a `.js` file then you cannot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery("body").css("color", "<?php echo $myvar; ?>");
</script>
```

Comment: change jQuery(body) with jQuery('body')

Comment: Contrary to what the OP wants, this sets a style rule rather than a class, and I don't see how it adds any knowledge.

Comment: @PeterHerdenborg Yes, but the OP's asking about a color name. Maybe I'm wrong, the op wants to use a class.

Comment: try using `<?=$myvar?>` it is a short code basicaly echoing the variable, so you don't have to write `<?php echo $myvar; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

yes, as long as your html file is interpreted by php (having .php/.phtml extension)

Comment: Yes it is an Wordpress site. I use this in a if to add that class on a specific page template.

Comment: then it should not be a problem, this is a proper use

Answer (score 0):

**I did it. Worked.
Correct is:**

```
jQuery('body').addClass("<?php echo $myvar; ?>");
```

**with**

```
jQuery('body')
```

**not**

```
jQuery(body)
```

Comment: Because body its not defined using jQuery(body).

Comment: yet again I would urge you to do this server side - it will then still work if a user has no javascript enabled. - see my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( is_page_template('nameOfYouTemplate.php') ) {

    echo '<body class='. $myvar .'>';

 } else {
    echo '<body>';
 }
```

Comment: Body already have few classes which are added by wordpress. I just need to add one more not to replace all classes with this one.